# Moog Minitaur port issues with FL Studio

Tags: synthesizer, fl-studio

I have several analog hardware synths.  I have been able to get all of them connected to FL Studio, but I've noticed the Moog Minitaur has to be reset every time.  The manual mentions that one should press all 4 buttons and then the next midi signal received will determine the port.  I have all the other synths permanently connected but this one.

How do I make the port/channel default?  I'm already forced to use port 1 for another synth, so I can't take that easy way out.  I just have to press the 4 buttons each time I connect.